# SpeechRecognizer on Android Wear

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, wear-os

The app I'm currently working on requires simple speech recognition of single words. However, I don't want to use:

> startActivityForResult() using the ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

because I need to display other stuff while the user is speaking.
So I tried this:

```
speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);        
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,"en");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

This should enable me to get results as well, however I always get:

> no selected voice recognition service

This code also return false:

```
boolean speechEnabled = SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(getApplicationContext());
```

So I think just using the `SpeechRecognizer` with `startListening` just doesn't work on Android Wear so far... Any suggestions on how I could implement a voice recognition without showing any specific UI?

EDIT:
I guess it has something to do with Google Voice search not being installed on the device, but installing it manually is no real option.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I tried a lot but nothing did the trick. Google did not respond to the problem either.

Comment: Have you tried [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net)? I'm not sure how many resources it requires, but on smartphones sphinx works just fine and is able to deliver decent quality for closed-vocabulary ASR.